# Project got deleted from my user directory

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I have both Windows and Ubuntu in my pc. Yesterday I cloned a git repo into my user directory namely `/home/my-name`. I then imported the project in eclipse.

Today when I started Ubuntu again this project is missing. On starting eclipse I see that the project is there but the files are missing. The path is the same.

My bash history didn't show any signs of project being removed. Why did this happen? Any ideas why this might have happened? Thanks !!

Comment: Did you clone the git repo to a subdirectory of your `/home/my-user` directory?

Comment: @Arronical No, I cloned it directly into /home/my-user

Comment: So it wasn't `/home/my-user/project` for the path?

Comment: @Arronical no it wasn't,  :( .....

Comment: In all likelihood, EGit simply moved the project to `~/.git` or some other pre-defined location. This is not about Ubuntu in any case.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your git files must have been overwritten when you rebooted, as you'd made the home directory the whole local git repo. Your user's home directory needs to contain certain files, such as `.profile` etc.

I think a safer way would be to make sure you clone to a directory within your user's home directory in future with:

```
git clone <git-source-repo> /home/user/project-name
```

Unfortunately that's not going to help you recover those lost files.

Comment: Thanks for the help dude, I have moved the project to Project folder, if it works well after the next 2-3 reboots, I'll accept your answer !! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: `git clone [url]` creates a new directory by default, unless you do `git clone [url] .`.

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP executed `git clone [url] /home/user`, but they'll need to confirm that.